# For Flurry error logging, where can I find the information that I logged?

Tags: ios, flurry, flurry-analytics

My errors are getting logged. I can see the errors in the log. I'm trying to figure out how to find the specific information that I'm logging, especially the `message` parameter.   I've tried looking through the documentation and clicking endlessly around the website with no luck.

I'm logging errors to flurry like this.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [Flurry logError:@"Location Error" message:error.localizedDescription error:error];
}
```

The error shows up in the log like this.

[image: Flurry error log]

How can I find the error message that I logged?

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? Trying to figure it out for myself as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just saw an answer in a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584528/130556).

In Flurry, go to `Technical` > `Errors`. Then at the bottom of the page it shows each error and its message.

Not super intuitive.